# Validation based on previous entries in the same List in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise

I am new to Sharepoint.

I am trying to create a site which has a list that stores loan information. The loan approval process is done by an Approval Workflow. I need to validate whether the person was approved a loan in the past year or rejected in the past six months. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use designer (assumption based on tags), [Sharepoint custom list validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924457).

I would use jQuery and [.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur) on `$('div[title^=People]')` (given it is a people picker), then use Client Object Model to do the validation.